# the movie sentence I can’t get it

Tags: sentence

I watched a movie ‘Girl Interrupted’ and there is a sentence ‘Can’t let you sit too long without popping the hood’ and I can’t get what this means.

Here is the scene. 
A nurse said to Jolie that ‘You said you would be in your room’ so Jolie talked back ‘Can’t let you sit too long without popping the hood’

And I put the video of that scene. 
https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/e9de6ea0-87cf-4650-a967-6c4357e483f0

Comment: "Popping the hood" is American slang that means "having a look."

Answer (score 0):

It just means to check on someone.
It could mean checking to see if they are okay, if a nurse said it.
In this movie, which looks like a psychiatric institution, the nurses have an easier time when patients are in their rooms and Jolie excuses her wandering around the corridors by humorously saying she was checking up on the nurses.